# Path separator for Atom / JavaScript on Windows

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, path-separator

I have developed an Atom package which calls SyncTeX (a utility for reverse lookup for LaTeX), and then opens in Atom the file specified in the SyncTeX response. I'm developing on Linux, but now a user on Windows tells me that this doesn't work.

In detail: SyncTeX returns a pathname like `C:\data\tex\main.tex`, with Windows-appropriate backslash separators. My package then calls `atom.workspace.open` with exactly that returned string, which leads to a JavaScript error (file not found).

Strangely, if the string is modified to use forward slashes instead, `C:/data/tex/main.tex`, the call works and the file is opened.

My questions:

1. Is this behavior specific to Atom, or to some underlying technology (JavaScript, Electron, Node, ...)? I was unable to find any documentation on this.
2. Since the replacement `\` → `/` is apparently necessary, is there a preferred way to implement it? Would a simple `String.replace` be adequate?
3. Do I risk breaking compatibility with other platforms if I always do the replacement?

Answer (score 1):

By my best knowledge paths with forward slashes '/' work well everywhere except Windows XP.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why backslashes wouldn't work on Windows?

Comment: I'm afraid I not quite understand your question. Backslashes should work on Windows. Within native Windows app at least. But some (almost all these days) apps use backslashes for special symbols (within text variables), like `\n` = `Enter`, `\t` = `Tab`, etc.You need to duplicate all backslashes \ => \\ . So, if you want to get `c:\temp\new.txt` you should use `c:\\temp\\new.txt` instead. Otherwise you will get `c:` `Tab` `emp` `Enter` `ew.txt`

Comment: This is not about a string literal in code, it's a string returned by an application. Backslash-escaping does not apply.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error "file not found" does mean that this string (whatever its source) was used as a "string literal" in the open file/folder function. It's obviously that Atom (and the most of modern apps) considers backslashes as special symbols in such cases.